# get value of list items which have "selected" class

Tags: jquery

I want jquery to loop through this list items and get value of anchor tag under li's which has selected class.
1) loop through list items
2) find li's with selected class
3) get values of anchor tags under li's which has selected class
4) push in array that values
5) this should be single loop.

with .each() it loops 3 times if it finds 3 li's with "selected" class and array.push is done 3 times and it should be 1 time.

```
<ul class="sizes-list">
   <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">32</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">34</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">36</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: on which event you want this loop ?

Comment: `$('.sizes-list .selected').each(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sizes-list">
   <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="abc.com">32</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="def.com">34</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">36</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        var selected = [];

        $('.sizes-list > li').each(function(i){
            if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
                selected.push($(this).find('a').text());
            }
        })

        alert(selected)
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector which directly select anchor element:

```js
$('.sizes-list li.selected > a').each(function(i, e) {
   alert($(e).text());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sizes-list">
  <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">32</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">34</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">36</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation in question, I want jquery to loop through list items and get anchor under li's with selected class and push them in array in single loop. right now it is looping through 3 time if it finds 3 li's with selected class.

Comment: you mean, get all the anchor with selected li class(2 elements), and store them inside array? What you want to store? is it its value or DOM itself?

Comment: its value like .text();

Comment: it's imposible. Because you need to iterate all the elements being capture to get its value. What the problem if using loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way...

```
$(function(){
   var listselected = $(".selected").length;
   console.log(listselected);
});
```

it will print the number of the selected lists in the console of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for something like this.  It doesn't require a loop and is designed for exactly this type of operation:

```js
var myArray = $('.sizes-list li.selected a').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
$('#result').html('RESULTING ARRAY: [' + myArray.toString() + ']');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sizes-list">
  <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">32</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">34</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">36</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: yet it still using loop implicitly.

Comment: right - but it's designed to do an operation and create an array - There's nothing wrong with `each()`, I just think `map()` is a more appropriate function for what's being asked.

Comment: yes your right, there is nothing wrong with `each` or any `loop`, OP just stating false explanation which avoid using loop(more than one). It just nonsense desire

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [];
$('.sizes-list li.selected > a').each(function() {
   a.push($(this).text());
 });
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sizes-list">
  <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">32</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">34</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">36</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
</ul>
```

I think this is your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var storVals = [];

$('li.selected > a').each(function(i, e) {
   storVals.push( e.text() );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayL=[];

$('.sizes-list li.selected > a').each(function(i,e){
    arrayL.push($(e).text());
 });

alert(arrayL);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sizes-list">
   <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="abc.com">32</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="def.com">34</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">36</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">38</a></li>
</ul>
```